# CAML return only 10 results

Tags: sharepoint, moss, caml

Is it possible using CAML to limit the amount of results returned. Say for example my query would pull back 25 results I would like the first 10 only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using [SPQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.aspx) then the [RowLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.rowlimit.aspx) property should do the trick.